# Is there a concise built-in way to get a list item by index that is not going to throw an exception?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I safely search a list for an object like this:

```
var someResult = myList.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.SomeValue == "SomethingHere");
```

If there are no objects that match my criteria then `someResult` is going to be null.

But if I only have the index of the object I want, things are not so nice.  I seem to have to so something like this:

```
try
{
    var someResult = myList[4];
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
{
    someResult = null;
}
```

I admit that is not terrible to have to write.  But it seems to me that there should be a way to just have the list return null if the index ends up being bogus.

Is there away to have a one (or two) line look up using **existing .net methods**?

(I know I could easily write an extension method, but I am wondering if there is a built in way to do this.)

Comment: If it returned null, you wouldn't know if it was because the index is out of range, or there was actually a null at that position in the list.

Comment: @hatchet - For the purposes of my application it amounts to the same thing (though I agree that sometimes you need to know that).  The accepted answer was exactly what I was hoping for on this.  (An existing extension method to get the value at index or null.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may be able to use the LINQ extension .ElementAtOrDefault() to achieve what you want.

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
Foo element = foos.ElementAtOrDefault(4);
```

However, you need to be careful that your generic type to `List<T>` is a reference type or a string, so the "default" returned to you is actually null.  The default you get back is default(T).

Comment: +1 Wow, nice. Hadn't seen that one before. Also according to the docs: "If the type of source implements IList<T>, that implementation is used to obtain the element at the specified index." so it's also efficient. So this is surely what the OP wants.

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly what I was hoping existed.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11):

I think you want [C.B.s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11422668/61974) of `ElementAtOrDefault` - go vote it up.

I have a few other points to add...

Regarding your try/catch solution:

> I admit that is not terrible to have to write.

Please *don't* use exceptions for this. Your approach is more verbose, exceptions are slow so you will get poor performance, and exceptions should only be used for exceptional situations.

---

It's also fairly easy to write this without LINQ by using the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
var someResult = myList.Count > 4 ? myList[4] : null;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can also use LINQ when you only have the index:

```
var someResult = myList
            .Select((x, i) => new { X = x, Index = i })
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Index == 4);
```

[Enumerable.Select Method (IEnumerable, Func)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869)

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form by incorporating
>   the element's index.

Answer (score 2):

[C B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11422668/480799) wins, but I can compete for second place, right?

```
var someResult = myList.Skip(4).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: +1 for ingenuity.  I have to say that I do like this one second best.

Comment: @ Vaccano Cool, thanks!  I'll add that although it's not the best solution for this particular problem, `Skip` is very useful in general for indexing and counting operations.  Want to modify `myList.Any()` to be able to see if it has more than n elements instead of 0?  Just change it to `myList.Skip(n).Any()`.